# State is not upating in renderer() component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I'm very new to react JS, and I am using it to build a app now. I have a question.

In of of the Button Click event i have a code logic like this:

```
handlestartbutton(event) {
     const accesskey = localStorage.getItem(localStorageKeys.accessTokenKey);
     const decodedAccessKey = jwt_decode(accesskey);
     const date = dateConverter.epochToReadableDate(decodedAccessKey.exp);
     if (date.currentTime < date.expiryDate) {
        this.setState({
         accesstokenexpirydate: true
        }, () => {
          if(this.state.accesstokenexpirydate === false) {
//rest of the code

      }
})
```

In renderer() i have a a pop up UI like this:

```
renderer()
{
{this.state.accesstokenexpirydate === true ? (
      <Popup
      open ={this.state.open}
         closeOnDocumentClick={false}
         closeOnEscape={false}
         onClose={this.closeModal}className
         >
         <div className={popstyles.popupBody}>
        <div className={popstyles.modalClose}>
        <a className="close" onClick={this.closeModal}>
        &times;
        </a>
        {""}
        <div className ={popstyles.unAutherizedUser}>
        <label >{homeConstantMessages.accessTokenExpire}</label>
        <div className ={popstyles.unAutherizedUserMsg}>
        <label>{homeConstantMessages.accessTokenExpireMsg}</label>
        <button className ={styles.refreshaccessbtn} onClick = {this.navigateToHomePage.bind(this)}  label = {homeConstantMessages.refreshbtn}>
         </button>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       </div>
      </Popup>
        ) : (
       ''
     )}
}
```

The problem is when the first time start button is clicked this pop up UI is not getting popped even though the  state variable accesstokenexpirydate is set to true. when second time the button is cicked UI is popping up. can anyone please help me out here

Comment: Can you check from where `this.state.open` is being set to true, isn't this is causing the problem?

Comment: Could you put 2 console logs in your code? After `if (date.currentTime < date.expiryDate) {` can you log `console.log('setting exp to true')` and in rerender: `console.log('in re render:',this.state.accesstokenexpirydate,this.state.accesstokenexpirydate===true)`

Comment: @RahulJain. You are right this.state.open is being set to true and this is causing the problem.

Comment: @HarshithR Did you identified from where the state is setting to true? I will put my comment as answer so that you can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

1) I think you have to apply arrow function like follows and then you can use **`this`**

```
handlestartbutton=(event)=> {...}
```

2) I'm quite confused about the name, don't you think it should be `render(...)` instead of `renderer()`

Comment: I'm sure when it was a binding issue it would produce an error and not set any state. Maybe OP is binding in constructor so arrow function would not solve it.